# Slide boxes with margin-left check if overslided

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a simple content/box slider which uses the following javascript:

```
$('#left').click(function () {
    $('#videos').animate({
        marginLeft: '-=800px'
    }, 500);
});
$('#right').click(function () {
    $('#videos').animate({
        marginLeft: '+=800px'
    }, 500);
});
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tjset/2/

What I want to do and I can't figure out how to show and hide arrows(left and right box) as the all the boxes slided.

So I clicked 4 time to the LEFT and slided all the boxes! then hide "left" so that you can't give more -800px

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is check after the animation completes to see if the `margin-left` property is smaller or larger than the bounds of the video `<div>`. If it is, depending on which navigation button was clicked, hide the appropriate navigation link.

Check out the code below:

```
$('#left').click(function () {
    // reset the #right navigation button to show
    $('#right').show();
    $('#videos').animate({
        marginLeft: '-=800px'
    }, 500, 'linear', function(){
        // grab the margin-left property
        var mLeft = parseInt($('#videos').css('marginLeft'));

        // store the width of the #video div
        // invert the number since the margin left is a negative value
        var videoWidth = $('#videos').width() * -1;

        // if the left margin that is set is less than the videoWidth var,
        //  hide the #left navigation. Otherwise, keep it shown
        if(mLeft < videoWidth){
            $('#left').hide();
        } else {
            $('#left').show();
        }
    });
});

// do similar things if the right button is clicked
$('#right').click(function () {
    $('#left').show();
    $('#videos').animate({
        marginLeft: '+=800px'
    }, 500, 'linear', function(){
        var mRight = parseInt($('#videos').css('marginLeft'));
        if(mRight > 100){
            $('#right').hide();
        } else {
            $('#right').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Check out the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dnVYW/1/

Comment: thnx that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

There are many jQuery plugins for this.  First determine how many results there are, then determine how many you want visible, then use another variable to keep track with how many are hidden to the left and how many are hidden to the right.  So...

`var total = TOTAL_RESULTS;
var leftScrolled = 0;
var rightScrolled = total - 3; // minus 3, since you want 3 displayed at a time.`

instead of using marginLeft I would wrap all of these inside of a wrapper and set the positions to absolute.  Then animate using "left" property or "right".  There's a lot of code required to do this, well not MUCH, but since there are many plugins, I think you'd be better off searching jquery.com for a plugin and look for examples on how to do this.  marginLeft is just not the way to go, since it can cause many viewing problems depending on what version of browser you are using.

Comment: I got it,when I am done with my code then I will try with left property as well. I care browser compatibality too. "that I dont use plugins is just for writing own code to learn"
thnx!